# Changing default error message when record not found - Laravel API

Tags: laravel, eloquent, error-handling

I am building a simple API, which there is a point that when the ID entered in the endpoint URL does not point to a valid record, I get a standard NotFoundHttpException. And I cannot figure out how to override this in order to provide my own error message response as I do not wish to share my Model name etc.

**Endpoint**
`Route::get('{mrl}', [MrlController::class, 'show']);`

**Controller**

```
public function show(Mrl $mrl)
    {
        if ($data = $mrl) {
            return response(['status' => 'ok', 'data' => $data], 200);
        } else {
            return response(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Could not retrieve data'], 500);
        }
    }
```

When I run this when a record exists I receive the following which is what I expect.

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "data": {
        "id": 98,
        "market_id": 1,
        "crop_id": 2,
        "chemical_id": 113,
        "maximum_residue_level": null,
        "exempt": 0,
        "comments": null,
        "date_verified": "2021-10-07",
        "created_at": "2021-10-19T05:42:12.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-19T05:42:12.000000Z"
    }
}
```

However, when I enter an ID in the route endpoint for a record that does not exist, I receive the following:

```
{
    "message": "No query results for model [App\\Seasonal\\Mrl] 99"
}
```

This is happening from what I understand to be the auto find of the record between the Route and the controller, and I am lost as to how to customize this behavior.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: *I do not wish to share my Model name etc* does it show that information when you change your environment to `production`?

Comment: Hi Brian, I get the same response when I change it to production. The only time it changes is when I enable debug mode and then it gives me the verbose error with callstack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending time reading the docs I finally found the answer on how to customize the behaviour if a record is found when utilising Eloquents Route Model Binding.

[In the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-missing-model-behavior), there is a method for this explicit purpose, to override the default behaviour when the bound model does not have a valid record.

The method for doing this is to chain the `->missing()` function call to the end of your route and then providing the behaviour for the response you wish to provide. As below:

```php
Route::get('{mrl}', [MrlController::class, 'show'])->missing(function () {
    return response(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Invalid query.'], 404);
});
```

Chaining this method onto my request has enabled me to return the generic response I was hoping for when querying an invalid model record.

[image: Desired response achieved]

Comment: Nice to see you found a way :)

Answer (score 1):

you don't show the code where you are fetchning the model from the database but we can assume something like that:

```
$mrl = Mrl::findOrFail($id);
show($mrl);
```

The model `findOrFail()` method throws an exception when the model is not found, which is convenient when you want to adapt the response.

You can imagine something like that:

```
try {
    $mrl = Mrl::findOrFail($id);
    return response(['status' => 'ok', 'data' => $data], 200);
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    return response(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Could not retrieve data'], 500);
}
```

The idea is to catch the error thrown by your model to change the message and status code of the response.

When building APIs you should event add a "generic" catch statement for any unhandled errors to display a standardized generic error message and log what happened, like this:

```
try {
    $mrl = Mrl::findOrFail($id);

    // Do more things that could generate errors ?

    return response(['status' => 'ok', 'data' => $data], 200);
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {

    // Not found
    return response(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Could not retrieve data'], 500);
} catch (\Exception $e) {

    // Generic error
    \Log::error($e);
    return response(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'An error occured'], 500);

}
```

Comment: Hi @ZarkDev, I am using the built in find from the route with the model dependency injection. When I am using `{$mrl}` in the route endpoint, and the controller method has the Model name with the same syntax `show(Mrl $mrl)` from the route to this method Laravel is automatically retrieving the record from the database, which is why I can then just check that it exists. At the point it enters my show method if the record doesn't exist it already errors. No matter what code I put inside the show method it never runs if there is not an existing record.

Comment: I feel like it's almost like the Base Model which my model extends has a default find method of findOrFail but I must be blind as I cannot find how to override this in my Model.